# Getting directory and directorates of a given path or use current working directory if no path is given

Tags: c

i have the following program working, but the problem is it only works when a path is given. I'm trying to find a way to set the path to current working directory if no path is given. For that i am using char *cdir = getcwd(0,0); I need to find a way to set that to argv, so that it points to that path instead of null. Can anyone check my code and tell me what i'm doing wrong. I am using a unix system to compile this.

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <unistd.h>


typedef struct stat Sub;
typedef struct dirent Dir;


void skimPath(const char *);

main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    Sub path;
    char *cdir = getcwd(0,0);

    if (argc <= 1)
    {
       /*
       this is the part i'm having trouble with, everything else works. I need a way to set  
       the path that is in cdir, to argv, so that it would work just like the case below      
       where argc is more than 2
       */

        argv = &cdir;
        printf("%s",argv);
        for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        {
            if (stat(*(argv + i), &path) == -1)
            {
                printf("WROTH PATH, DIRECTORY NOT FOUND \n%s\n", *(argv + i) ); 
                continue; 
            }

            if (S_ISDIR(path.st_mode)) 
                skimPath(*(argv + i));
        }
    }

    if (argc >= 2)
    {

        for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        {
            if (stat(*(argv + i), &path) == -1)
            {
                printf("WROTH PATH, DIRECTORY NOT FOUND \n%s\n", *(argv + i) ); 
                continue;
            }

            if (S_ISDIR(path.st_mode)) 
                skimPath(*(argv + i));

        }
    }
}


void skimPath(const char *dirName)
{
    char str[100];
    DIR *dir;
    Sub path;
    Dir *d;
    if ((dir = opendir(dirName)) == NULL)
    {
        printf(str, "File or Directory Could Not Open");
    }

    while ((d = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {
        // check if directory is d or d's paren   
        if (strcmp(d->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(d->d_name, "..") == 0) 
            continue; // if ture rest will be ignored from while loop

        // saves in a buffer pointed by str
        sprintf(str, "%s/%s", dirName, d->d_name);


        if (stat(str, &path) == -1)
        {
            continue;
        }

        //checks to see if its a d
        if (S_ISDIR(path.st_mode))
        {
            printf("%s \n",d->d_name);

            // directory goes in str
            skimPath(str);

        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Yes I could - Three hours work. £300 and it is done

Comment: @EdHeal: That just made me think about moving to Scotland :D

Comment: @LihO - I hope not for the sunshine!

Comment: See also [How to set `argv` to point to the current working path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460604/how-to-set-the-argv-to-point-to-the-current-working-path)

Answer (score 1):

We can analyze your code, but what you're trying to do is fairly bizarre (in detail — there are other ways to do what you want, I think).

```
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    Sub path;
    char *cdir = getcwd(0,0);
```

Since you don't always use `cdir`, you could — should — declare it inside the block where you use it.  `getcwd()` is an expensive function, especially if you've got multiple mounted file systems to deal with, and especially NFS-mounted file systems.

```
    if (argc <= 1)
    {
       /*
       this is the part i'm having trouble with, everything else works. I need a way to set  
       the path that is in cdir, to argv, so that it would work just like the case below      
       where argc is more than 2
       */

        argv = &cdir;
```

This statement is 'legitimate', but you've not thought through the consequences.  You now have `argv` pointing at precisely one string (no null termination on the list of pointers) and `argc` is now immaterial.

```
        printf("%s",argv);
```

This is wrong; it should be one of these lines:

```
printf("%s\n", argv[0]);
printf("%s\n", *argv);
printf("%s\n", cdir);
```

You've zapped your original argument list and the only argument left is the current directory.

```
        for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        {
```

Since `argv` now points at `cdir`, you can't iterate over the arguments.  Doubly, you can't do that starting at index 1.

```
            if (stat(*(argv + i), &path) == -1)
```

Yes, you can write `argv[i]` like that, but why would you do so?

```
            {
                printf("WROTH PATH, DIRECTORY NOT FOUND \n%s\n", *(argv + i) ); 
                continue; 
            }
```

While you will find 'wroth' in a decent dictionary ('adj (archaic): angry'), you probably mean 'wrong'. And SHOUTING at people is unkind.  Also, error messages are best printed to standard error; that's what it is for.  And if you used an `else` (or `else if`) you could avoid the `continue`.

```
            if (S_ISDIR(path.st_mode)) 
                skimPath(*(argv + i));
        }
    }
```

This much is OK.

```
    if (argc >= 2)
    {
        ...
    }
```

I'd write this as an `else` clause for the current code structure.

Since you'll do the same thing if the user explicitly passes the name `.` as an argument, it is very tempting to fake things by providing the current directory as the first argument if the user didn't provide one.  Since when you enter the `main()`, the condition `argv[argc] == NULL` is true, you can actually write:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc == 1)
        argv[argc++] = ".";

    assert(argc > 1);
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        ...code from the if (argc >= 2) part of your code...
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you needed to insert more than one argument, you'd have to go through a bit more of a rigmarole, more like:

```
if (argc < XXX)
{
    static char *alt_argv[] = { 0, "xyz", "pqr", "abc", 0 };
    alt_argv[0] = argv[0];
    argv = alt_argv;
    argc = (sizeof(alt_argv) / sizeof(alt_argv[0])) - 1;
}
```

Despite warnings from others, `argc` and `argv` are local variables in the `main()` function and can be modified (carefully).  It is more nearly dodgy to modify the data in `argv[argc]`, but it depends on whether your code uses the null pointer sentinel or uses the count.  If you use the count and never access beyond the (modified) `argv` array end, you'll be fine.  If you do access beyond the end, you're trampling on (or reading from) your environment variables on most variants of Unix.

If you do decide you want the absolute path name of the current directory used, then you can still adapt the scheme I outlined to work with that.  Assuming that you are working on Linux or a BSD-derived platform, your version of `getcwd()` will allocate memory when given a null pointer, so you can write:

```
if (argc == 1)
    argv[argc++] = getcwd(NULL, 0);
```

The only thing to watch for is a null pointer:

```
for (i = 1; i < argc && argv[i] != NULL; i++)
    ...
```

---

When you need to do the job in real life instead of practicing the basic system calls, consider using [`nftw()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nftw.html)
to traverse the directory hierarchy for you.

Comment: +1 for an amazing answer. I was the one who advised against modifying `argv`, but I did not mean that it wasn't *doable* - just that it needed care, which made it probably not worthwhile in this instance, unless someone supplied a detailed howto :-)